# How to get rid of the MKBalloonCalloutView in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkuserlocation

I have the following code which works for `iOS 13` and lower.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    mapView.userLocation.title = "You are here"
    mapView.userLocation.subtitle = // user's location
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) {
        return nil
    }
}
```

It shows only the blue dot without a callout and above the blue dot is just the title and subtitle.

[image]

But on iOS 14 there is a default MKBalloonCalloutView that appears in place of the title and subtitle. It shows a gray profileImage. How can I get rid of the BalloonCallout so I can show just the title and subtitle?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By setting your own detail `detailCalloutAccessoryView` for the User Location annotation's `MKAnnotationView` the behaviour reverts to just showing title and subtitle.

You can set any `UIView` of your choice, like an `UIImageView` for example, or just an empty one.

For example in your `MKMapViewDelegate`

```swift
func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
    mapView.view(for: mapView.userLocation)?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = .init()
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I was working on another project and I didn't have time to dig into the project that uses MKMapView. Anyhow, your answer semi works. The issue is the `title` shows but the `subtitle` doesn't; appear. Do you have any idea what the problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

For the user (the one from the question), if using `iOS 14` and higher I use `MKMarkerAnnotationView`,. If using `iOS 13` or lower I use `MKPinAnnotationView`. I have a separate custom pin for everyone else:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let reuseIdentifier = "MyIdentifier"

    if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) {

        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            if let pin = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
                
                return setMKMarkerAnnotationView(pin: pin)
            }
        } else {
            let pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            pin.canShowCallout = true
            return pin
        }
        return nil

    } else {

        // dequeue the custom pins for everyone else
    }
}

func setMKMarkerAnnotationView(pin: MKMarkerAnnotationView) -> MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    
    pin.animatesWhenAdded = true
    
    pin.markerTintColor = UIColor.red
    pin.titleVisibility = .visible
    pin.subtitleVisibility = .visible
    
    return pin
}
```